# Return json from web api controller

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

I have web api controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public String UploadFile()
    {//do some logic
       String jsResult="{\"success\":\"false\", \"msg\":\"No file or user ID!\"}";
       return jsResult;
    }
```

Returned string to the client is like this:  "{\"success\":\"false\", \"msg\":\"No file or user ID!\"}";

I compose json string manually but client doesn't parse it(I guess because returned string is escaped with "\".
What would be the proper way to return json string to the clinet from this controller method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try auto serialize webapi:

Create a Model:

```
public class UploadResult
{
    public UploadResult()
    {

    }
    public bool Success  { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
}
```

And return

```
public UploadResult UploadFile()
{
    var r = new UploadResult(){ Success = false, Msg = "No file or user ID!" };
    return r;
}
```

In your example, you are explicitly serializing, and the result ends up serialized twice. Because WebApi already has the Json serializer in the pipeline.

To go async:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    var r = new UploadResult(){ Success = false, Msg = "No file or user ID!" };
    // some "await" logic
    return Ok(r);
}
```

Adding  `using System.Web.Mvc` fails because

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]  != [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
```

And [HttpPost] is ambiguous. Anyway, **the Mvc ref is not necessary** . Remove it and add again [HttpPost]

Comment: I have ApiController: 
public class ImportReservationController : ApiController
It doesn't have JsonResult  option.
If i add reference(using System.Web.Mvc;) then i can write JsonResult, but [HttpPost] doesn't work then.
I guess API controller doesn't support JsonResult.

Comment: It works now. Can you explain me in couple of words since i'm new to web api. And why if I add reference to MVC it stops working?
[HttpPost] is not available any more. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Other option would be to add like this:
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
And than I would be able to use JsonResult result?

Comment: Hi, what if procedure returns result as table. What would be the best way to return table as json result?

Comment: In that case, maybe you need think in a object that supports pagination. That object should have a IEnumerable with your Rows, current page, page offset, total of rows... then .net writes the  json result.

Comment: Do you have some example? It is probably very common request(could be with link to entities)

Comment: It's a "too broad" Q&A , try to define which UI component you will use. ( jquery, angular, datatables jq... pure html & css ) . For server side, you can resolve only with .net native code. And... Don't test the patience of this community:  You must make the effort to create a piece of code and if necessary create a new question. Check http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ for conceptual questions about software development

Comment: Thanks. It is everything clear now. i will open a new question.

Comment: Hi Mate, your solution doesn't work in IE.
IE always tries to download or open returned json response.
I have extjs call to my web Api and inside webApiConfig.js i have this line:
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.MediaTypeMappings.Add(new RequestHeaderMapping("Accept", "text/html", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, true, "application/json"));
What to do? Any idea?

Comment: The Async example you gave works beautifully!  Thanks for pushing that example out there.  Comes in handy with firebase database.net

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadFile()
{//do some logic
   String jsResult="{\"success\":\"false\", \"msg\":\"No file or user ID!\"}";
   return Json(jsResult);
}
```

I've changed the return type to JsonResult and used the Json method to format your result.